# Human body part detection in Android

Tags: android, api, android-camera, face-detection

Currently I am working on Google face detection `API` from this `API` I am able to detect human complete face (eye, nose and other parts) and also as per this concept I have developed one application, if you stand in front of the front face camera then it will detect your face and show some gestures.

```
Context context = Applications.getAppContext();

FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .build();

detector.setProcessor(
         new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory())
         .build());

if (!detector.isOperational()) {

}

mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
            .build();
```

Application video link which i have developed till now :-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/097todfu90ic12j/VirtualMirror.mp4?dl=0

Application play store link:-

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twins.virtualmirror

Is there any API available where we can recognize human other body parts (Chest, hand, legs and other parts of the body), because as per the Google vision `API` it's only able to detect face of the human not other parts.

Comment: Image recognition is a broad topic and asking for APIs or off site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: hey thanks can i use this SDK http://catchoom.com/

Comment: Theoretically, a lot of machine learning goes into how to "detect" any object from an image or video.  https://backchannel.com/how-google-s-new-photos-app-can-tell-cats-from-dogs-ffd651dfcd80#.bfgqnrr3q

Comment: Any progress on this? I want to make an app just like wanna kicks. Its an early access app on playstore which instantly detect your foot and place a shoe on it. Its blazingly fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2021**

You can train a Convolutional Neural Network to detect any body part. I recommend you to learn machine learning from scratch But if you don't have time.  you can use [google auto ml](https://cloud.google.com/automl).

**Old Answer**

Currently there is no API for  detecting other body parts. If you wants to detect other body parts you have to code , It wont be easy but not Impossible

Comment: hey thanks but can you please tell me some sample code, so that i can follow because i have no idea how to start

Answer (score 3):

Did you see now many camera software provide facility to capture image when you show your hand to camera. That camera software can detect palm of your hand.

So it is already done by someone ....

But there is no Google api for this...

You have to use third party or customize yourself...

There is an api i know named [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). they already create api fro body part detection for Computer Version. I am not sure they release or not for Android.

[Here is a demo in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6c8UQ7si8GA)

Comment: Thanks yes same thing i am also thinking because this concept is little tricky and needs to write our own logic